# How can I do model binding and data display at the same time using the same model.list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have a code similar to this:

**My View**

```
@model MyCode.Models.RemarksModel

foreach (var row in Model.List)
{
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><font class="font_table_content">@row.Id</font></td>
    <td align="center"><font class="font_table_content">@row.Full_Name</font></td>
    <td align="center"><font class="font_table_content">@Html.TextBox("row.Remarks")</font></td>
}
```

**My Model**

```
public class RemarksModel
{
    public IList<UserRemarks> List { get; set; }
}
```

**My UserRemarks Object**

```
public class UserRemarks
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Full_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Remarks { get; set; }
}
```

Next in my controller, I will have some code that will load the records into a IList from the DB via Nhibernate, and then return the view with the list inside the model, something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RemarksTest()
    {
         RemarksModel model = new RemarksModel();
         model.List = LoadTheList();
         return View(model);
    }
```

Now, what I want to ask is, how am I able to **receive** the list back, i.e. get the remarks value back?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemarksTest(RemarksModel model)
    {
         var list = model.list;
         foreach (var remarks in list)
         {
               //do something to save the input data into code.
         }

         return View(model);
    }
```

The actual code is more complex, and I've read about those IDictionary methods to receive the values. However implementing them, will cause the values **not** to be displayed instead, since the code no longer refers to the model.list.

Any ideas how can I display, and yet also, receive the data using the same 'list' inside my model above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need change your view as follows:

```
@model IEnumerable<UserRemarks>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    for(int i=0; i<@Model.Count; i++) 
    {
        <table> 
        <tr> 
            <td align="center"><font class="font_table_content">@Html.TextboxFor(m => m[i].Id)</font></td> 
            <td align="center"><font class="font_table_content">@Html.TextboxFor(m => m[i].Full_Name</font></td> 
            <td align="center"><font class="font_table_content">@Html.TextboxFor(m => m[i].Remarks")</font></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    }

    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

Then the get action should be changed to:

```
[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult RemarksTest() 
    { 
         List<UserRermarks> model = LoadTheList();
         return View(model);
    }
```

And the post action changed to:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult RemarksTest(IEnumerable<UserRemarks> model) 
    { 
         foreach (var remarks in model) 
         { 
               //do something to save the input data into code. 
         } 

         return View(model); 
    }
```

Unfortunately I don't have visual studio on the computer I am working on so I am unable to test the above but the logic should be correct so if a problem occurs it may just be that I have typed something slightly a miss.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Did some slight modifications. Got it to work in a similar concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your GET controller action you could store the list in `TempData`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RemarksTest()
{
     RemarksModel model = new RemarksModel();
     model.List = LoadTheList();
     TempData['List'] = model.List;
     return View(model);
}
```

Then in your POST action retrieve it with:

```
var myList = TempData['List']
```

If your app is stateless (i.e. no sessions), then you can use [a cookie-based TempData provider](http://davidmorgantini.blogspot.com/2010/12/cookie-temp-data-provider.html).

Comment: however, I need to 1) display the values of the list to the users, and then accept any changes to the values in the list. your provided solution does not solve the problem. even if i keep the stuff in TempData, however I still can't receive the values that have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are just displaying the values.
To post values to server back, you need to have some inputs (like, textbox,checkbox,radiobutton,hiddenfields). In your case you can define hidden fields ,so that model binder will bind them to List of UserRemarks.

Follow http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx to bind a list to model.

Comment: Hi, not fully understanding your reply. I have this: @Html.TextBox("row.Remarks") which is an input. Yet when checking the values in my controller, the RemarksModel object's list is null.