# MVC 3 - C# - Submit Form with a Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view that contain a table with rows and 3 editable columns

Col1: First Name
 Col2: Age
 Col3: Year

And you can have many rows of this data and edit it..

Is it better to do a Form Submit or have jquery Submit the data to the controller?

How do define the Controller to handle this type of submit?  Do I just give each ROW,COL and name and then use the FormCollection to loop through?  It seems like I should be able to define a list as a param in the controller..

any suggestions?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443758/how-can-i-do-model-binding-and-data-display-at-the-same-time-using-the-same-mode

Comment: Yes.  I saw that post 5 minutes later.. thanks.  I ended up using a list JSON and serialized it to a C# model. Works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it matters much how you submit it, do whatever works best with your UI/validation/etc.

You can bind your controller action to an array/list/collection. Take a look at this...

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Remember - you aren't actually submitting a table to your Controller. You are submitting data in some format. The table is just a way of displaying that data. I can just as easily display JSON data in a table as I could XML data as I could CSV data.

So, what you really need is to have your controller define the data that it expects (this could be JSON, a model object, or just a list of parameters), and then send that data in your form submission (whether you do it with jQuery, via the Html form helpers, or whatever).

I know this is overly generic with respect to a solution, but I wanted to make it clear that you aren't going to submit a "table" to your controller. A table is just a way of displaying your underlying data. What you need to think about is how is that data being represented. Solve that, and everything else should become more clear.